# Pivot without aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to turn some parts of my rows into columns. To my knowledge, I am only able to use a pivot with an aggregate function,but I would just be pivoting text. For each client I have up to 4 rows grouped by a DLSEQUENCE field. Instead of having the 4 rows, I would like everything to be on 1 row.

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN Sched_time BETWEEN TRUNC(SCHED_TIME) + INTERVAL  '8' HOUR + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
                         AND TRUNC(SCHED_TIME) + INTERVAL '14' HOUR + INTERVAL '45' MINUTE AND
          TO_CHAR(SCHED_TIME, 'DY') IN ('MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI')
        THEN 'ABC' 
        ELSE 'DEF'
   END AS Organization,
   Client_Last_Name,
   Client_First_Name,
   Sched_Time,  
   Field_Name,
   CASE 
        WHEN Recoded_Response = '1' THEN 'Yes'
        WHEN Recoded_Response = '2' THEN 'No'
        ELSE Recoded_Response
    END AS Responses,
   Dlsequence
FROM DAILY_LOG_CUSTOM_DATA 
WHERE SERVICE_NAME = 'Medical'
AND FIELD_CATEGORY = 'Background Information'
AND Field_Name IN
(
'Restraint?',
'History',
'Findings',
'Treatment'
)
AND Sched_Time >= TO_DATE('2020-03-01 01:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS') 
AND Sched_Time  < TO_DATE('2020-03-31 12:59:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
Order BY Dlsequence
```

Here is my table:

[image]

I would like the response fields that go with ('Restraint?','History','Findings','Treatment') to have their own column for each DLSEQUENCE field.

[image]

Comment: Pivot or conditional aggregation requires aggregate functions. You can use max() or min() for text. What if you have two rows for same dlsequence and History? You can use listagg() for example. Or you can show them in two separate rows using row_number() at first. Everything depends if such situation is possible and what do you want in this case.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data - instead, post them both as formatted text. This allows people to copy the text and manipulate it as needed to help duplicate your problem and find an answer to your question. Also, please include an example of the results you expect, worked out using your test data, so people can see what you're trying to get. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica - I am working on getting you the formatted text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you had in mind:

```
SELECT DLSEQUENCE,
       ORGANIZATION,
       CLIENT_LAST_NAME,
       CLIENT_FIRST_NAME,
       SCHED_TIME,
       LISTAGG("Restraint?", ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DLSEQUENCE) AS "Restraint?",
       LISTAGG("Findings", ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DLSEQUENCE) AS "Findings",
       LISTAGG("History", ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DLSEQUENCE) AS "History",
       LISTAGG("Treatment", ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DLSEQUENCE) AS "Treatment"
  FROM (SELECT DLSEQUENCE,
               ORGANIZATION,
               CLIENT_LAST_NAME,
               CLIENT_FIRST_NAME,
               SCHED_TIME,
               CASE
                 WHEN FIELD_NAME = 'Restraint?' THEN RESPONSES
                 ELSE NULL
               END AS "Restraint?",
               CASE
                 WHEN FIELD_NAME = 'Findings' THEN RESPONSES
                 ELSE NULL
               END AS "Findings",
               CASE
                 WHEN FIELD_NAME = 'History' THEN RESPONSES
                 ELSE NULL
               END AS "History",
               CASE
                 WHEN FIELD_NAME = 'Treatment' THEN RESPONSES
                 ELSE NULL
               END AS "Treatment"
          FROM YOUR_TABLE)
  GROUP BY DLSEQUENCE,
           ORGANIZATION,
           CLIENT_LAST_NAME,
           CLIENT_FIRST_NAME,
           SCHED_TIME
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f937c78190726c5a40326b6497b8da4e)

Comment: That's it! I will have to work on `listagg()` functions for the future. Thank you.